# Parallel block in SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm stucked with a next problem:

I have a parallel block in SPD Workflow, each of parallel thread - task for different groups of employees.
Everything is ok if everybody agree and click "Approve" or disagree and click "Reject".

But it should be one more option - "Remake"
Every group have a possibility to send the task back to initiator for adding or fixing some info.
After initiator finishes his task he close it and it should go to the stage where it came from.

And after all remarks fixed and everybody clicked "Approve" workflow leave the parallel block.

I really do not know how implement this logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all solved it with loop activity.
It is so simple)

I've done next steps:
1. Inserted parallel block
2. Inserted three steps that I need (SPGroup1, SPGroup2, SPGroup3)
3. Firstly I assign task to each group in each step
4. Then inserted check condition loop activity
5. Inside it I check whether task result above equals "Remake"
6. If yes I assign task to initiator
7. After If condition assign task again to group
8. And finally write to task result variable on the top task result variable from the last task to group

You can find the screenshot below, sorry for russian localization
[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/51601)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll edit it right now

Answer (score 0):

You can use a task process to create a approval process. 
When the user complete you can take the result and execute some task according with result.

You can see more in this [post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj614606.aspx)

Comment: Yep, I know it. But what about 3 tasks which must assign in parallel?

Comment: Yep, a process to each.

Comment: ok, and if one of them is going to send it to initiator and click "remake" button - how should I assign task to initiator? cause every task in parallel block is waiting anothers to be closed.

Comment: You can create a workflow in the task list to address what will be done after the completion of the task.

Comment: good advise, thank you. but it won't work in my case cause I have to have only one main workflow cause in my process i show the history to users. This way it's going to be two separate workflows.